# How can I make this function work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays set up that I wish to multiply each value within each together. Then I want to get the total value in the form of a variable. I will post what I have below. I think my problem may be that I am not sure how to get each run of the code to add together?

```
var flatQty=[];
flatQty[0]= document.getElementById("flats1").value;
flatQty[1]= document.getElementById("flats2").value;
flatQty[2]= document.getElementById("flats3").value;
flatQty[3]= document.getElementById("flats4").value;
flatQty[4]= document.getElementById("flats5").value;

var flatWidth=[];
flatWidth[0]=document.getElementById("flatwidth1").value;
flatWidth[1]=document.getElementById("flatwidth2").value;
flatWidth[2]=document.getElementById("flatwidth3").value;
flatWidth[3]=document.getElementById("flatwidth4").value;
flatWidth[4]=document.getElementById("flatwidth5").value;

for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
var flatCharge=flatWidth[i]*2*flatQty[i];
}

document.getElementById("flatTest").innerHTML=flatCharge;
```

When I run the code nothing is printed into the id="flatTest".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problems is that you are redefining your `flatCharge` inside the loop, therefore it's not correct outside the loop. In addition, you are not adding the values, but replacing them on every iteration of the loop. Change the loop to this:

```
var flatCharge = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    flatCharge += flatWidth[i] * 2 * flatQty[i];
};

document.getElementById("flatTest").innerHTML = "" + flatCharge;
```

and it should work.

Comment: that's not strictly correct - the declaration will be hoisted.  However the value will be _overwritten_ in each pass, so the value displayed will be the last value calculated.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but he also said "When I run the code nothing is printed into the id="flatTest"." With his old code, there should atleast be the last loop printed. So there is a problem somewhere else also. Anyway +1

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I suspect he wasn't filling in all five pairs during testing

Comment: Could also be a DOM-not-loaded issue.

Comment: @Alnitak My comment was for Aleks, I just posted it right when you posted you, but what I meant was exactly what you said!

Comment: This solution is only giving me the last calculation which would array position[4] I need to add them all togather?

Comment: my (deleted) answer still partly stands too - there should be a caveat that any _addition_ operation might require that the strings be converted to numbers first, to avoid confusing addition with string concatenation.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, you're right, there's probably something else missing/wrong in the OP's code, what it is though is impossible to say from the list.

Comment: @ABBryan if you're getting NaN, then most likely one of your fields contains something other than a number.  When it's then converted to number for multiplication, you get this error.

Comment: Got it fixed thank you to all, there was a DOM error. Quick question though what does the += operator actually do?

Comment: `a += b` is the same as `a = a + b`

Comment: aah so it adds each time to the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

`.value` properties are *strings*, not *numbers*. so you should be careful how you handle them.  Multiplication actually works for strings, but not for addition where the `+` operator performs concatenation instead.

There are numerous methods of converting from string to number:

- `+s` - will convert the expression `s` into a number
- `parseFloat(s)`
- `parseInt(s, 10)` for whole numbers

The actual problem in your code is that you're overwriting the calculated value in each pass using the `=` operator instead of `+=`.

I suggest refactoring your entire code thus to avoid all of the repetition:

```
var flatCharge = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    var qty = +document.getElementById('flats' + i).value;
    var width = +document.getElementById('flatwidth' + i).value;

    if (!isNaN(qty) && !isNaN(width)) {
        flatCharge += 2 * qty * width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Multiplication on strings performs an implicit *toNumber* conversion.

Comment: ha, so it does.  damn.  I was thinking of addition.